# Polymer - Ripple Animation Skews Hero Animation

Tags: polymer

I was hoping someone more knowledgeable about Polymer could help me figure out this problem. I have created a bare-bones app to demonstrate the problem I am having in my website. Essentially, I am running into issues with the ripple animation skewing my hero animation. If I remove the ripple animation, I get a normal hero animation, but when I add the ripple animation back in it distorts the hero animation.

Here is the difference I am talking about(Look at red box and how it stretches):

[Without Ripple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lni04.gif)

[With Ripple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si6aE.gif)

Here is some of my code

test-app.html

```
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="test-app">

    <template>
        <style>
            neon-animated-pages{
                position:relative;
                height:100%;
            }
            .box{
                border:5px solid black;
                width:500px;
                height:500px;
                position:relative;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="box">
            <neon-animated-pages on-click="switchPages" selected="{{openNeonPage}}">
                <hero-test-card></hero-test-card>
                <hero-test-fixed></hero-test-fixed>
            </neon-animated-pages>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'test-app',
        properties:{
            openNeonPage:{
                type:'String',
                value:"0"
            }
        },

        switchPages:function(event){
            if(this.openNeonPage == "0")
                this.openNeonPage = "1";
            else
                this.openNeonPage = "0";
        }
    });
</script>
```

hero-test-card.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="hero-test-card">

    <template>
        <style>
            div{
                position:absolute;
                width:150px;
                height:150px;
                background: red;
            }
        </style>

        <div id="card">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

    </template>


</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'hero-test-card',
        behaviors: [
            Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior
        ],
        properties:{
            animationConfig:{
                value:function(){
                    return{
                        'exit':[{
                            name:'hero-animation',
                            id:'hero',
                            fromPage:this,
                        },{
                            name:'ripple-animation',
                            id:'ripple',
                            fromPage:this
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            sharedElements:{
                value:function(){
                    return{
                        'hero':this.$.card,
                        'ripple':this.$.card
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

hero-test-fixed.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="hero-test-fixed">

    <template>
        <style>
            #fixed{
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                background: green;
                bottom:0;
                right:0;
            }
            #card{
                position:absolute;
                width:150px;
                height:150px;
                bottom:0;
                right:0;
                background:red;
            }
        </style>

        <div id="fixed">
                <div id="card">
                    <p>content</p>
                </div>
        </div>

    </template>


</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'hero-test-fixed',
        behaviors: [
            Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior
        ],
        properties:{
            animationConfig:{
                value:function(){
                    return{
                        'entry':[{
                            name:'ripple-animation',
                            id:'ripple',
                            toPage:this
                        },{
                            name:'hero-animation',
                            id:'hero',
                            toPage:this,

                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            sharedElements:{
                value:function(){
                    return{
                        'hero':this.$.card,
                        'ripple':this.$.fixed
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animation.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-shared-element-animatable-behavior.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/ripple-animation.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/scale-down-animation.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/slide-from-right-animation.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/fade-in-animation.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/animations/hero-animation.html">
        <link rel="import" href="elements/card-for-tile.html">
        <link rel="import" href="elements/tile-container.html">
        <link rel="import" href="elements/raw-tile.html">
        <link rel="import" href="elements/test-app.html">
        <link rel="import" href="elements/hero-test-card.html">
        <link rel="import" href="elements/hero-test-fixed.html">

        <!-- <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html"> -->
        <style>
            html, body{
                height:100%;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body fullbleed unresolved>
        <test-app></test-app>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here is the example I modeled after: http://morethanreal.github.io/neon-animation-demo/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/grid/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured out my own answer relatively quickly. To avoid future headaches for everyone, the problem was that I had a nested div element. I was adding the ripple animation to its child, the red box(not explicitly). This was the cause of the skew on the red box.